# wpf image from xaml not shown on run

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

Add an Image Controller to xaml with source image.

The image is shown on xaml, but when I run the program the source image is not shown.

`<Image x:Name="MainImage" Source="sample.jpg"></Image>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by others here you should include you images in your projects as a resource, that is unless you should load images from IE the users pictures folder. But hardcoding a path like that is bad pie, particulary using even drive number that only works on your machine.

In cases you where you need to load images from a users disk, bind the source, use a bitmap image and load it in your viewmodel instead.

XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding YourImage}" />
```

In your viewmodel define the YourImage property as a BitmapImage, then load it from your code.

Using images as resources as mentioned by @Clemens above;

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/yournamespace;component/Images/sample.jpg"/>
```

Note that the long corny pack://application:.. line. this is not required, but it makes WPF find images when you are dealing with other assemblies I.E plugins or just plain DLL files. If they are not included, they will not be found. That is if they are not all declared within your application project.

Hope it helps,

cheers

Stian